# Axis Webservice Header Security Password Text

Tags: security, axis, usernametoken

I am new to security headers and I need your help. I can do axis webservices call with authentication, thats easy but struggling with security. 
I have the following security header which is failing to authentic and i know it is becuase of the username token becuase i get exception: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: An invalid security token was provided (An error happened processing a Username Token).

**this is a working request from soapui**:

`<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
            <wsse:Username>tibco-admin</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">secret</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">d6zrRrsSdfulAUmTq6VFtQ==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2014-01-07T15:55:58.816Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>`

**This is a request that is failing from java:**

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2">
     <wsse:Username xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">tibco-admin</wsse:Username>
     <wsse:Password EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText" xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">secret</wsse:Password>
     <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">XY7Kb6UcEhloWOlmcbDlGg==</wsse:Nonce>
     <wsse:Created xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">2014-01-07T17:48:39Z</wsse:Created>
 </wsse:UsernameToken>
```

**My java code is:**

```
            //set header
            SOAPHeaderElement wsseSecurity =  new SOAPHeaderElement(new PrefixedQName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd","Security", "wsse"));
            wsseSecurity.setMustUnderstand(true);
            wsseSecurity.setAttribute("xmlns:wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
            wsseSecurity.setActor(null);

            //set userNameToken
            SOAPElement userNameToken = wsseSecurity.addChildElement("UsernameToken", "wsse");
            userNameToken.setAttribute("wsu:Id", "UsernameToken-1");

            //set username
            SOAPElement userName = userNameToken.addChildElement("Username", "wsse");
            userName.setValue("tibco-admin");

            //set password
            SOAPElement password = userNameToken.addChildElement("Password", "wsse");
            password.setAttribute("EncodingType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
            password.setValue("secret");

            //set nonce
            SOAPElement nonce = userNameToken.addChildElement("Nonce", "wsse");
            nonce.setValue("XY7Kb6UcEhloWOlmcbDlGg==");
            nonce.setAttribute("EncodingType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary");

            //set created
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(new Date());
    String timestamp = DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(c);
    timestamp = timestamp.substring(0, 19);
    timestamp = timestamp+"Z";
            SOAPElement created = userNameToken.addChildElement("Created", "wsse");
            created.setValue(timestamp);

            stub.setHeader(wsseSecurity);

            System.out.println(wsseSecurity);
    stub.setUsername("tibco-admin");
    stub.setPassword("secret");
```

I hardcoded the value for nonce for testing.

Any help or pointers would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, i made a silly typo in my code,

I set the attribute name for the following as EncodingType which failed it. It should be:

```
password.setAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error is in password,

try to

"password.setAttribute("**Type**", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
            password.setValue("secret");"

Answer (score -2):

SOAPElement created = userNameToken.addChildElement("Created", "wsu","http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :-) Please provide some explanation why your suggestion helps answer the question. That will provide value to your contribution. If you have questions, please consult the guidelines in the StackOverflow Help Center.